# Restoring postgres backup fails and an undelete-able file with a bizarre name (???2@ؾ>?yqus????>I?[ޏI??i?Ď) shows up in /home/myuser

Tags: linux, postgresql, azure, heroku, pg-restore

I have a postgresql DB on an Azure VM with Linux installed. I need to restore a certain backup to it from a file called `latest.dump`. I copied this file to `/home/myuser` and then ran `psql mydb < latest.dump`.

A lot of gibberish got output on the screen, e.g.

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb3
invalid command \Jg�~J&�:�Qr�Ɩ����q���^�[1�����q)���G���҆C�|�
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb5
invalid command \mJ�q����>�^�R����
invalid command \R
                  ܡI$�)�a�;���wg7Ei�}R%�Q����h&ஓ�L��܆��(
invalid command \I����3M��e�2Q�?/X������`+=|Y[``+��:��r
invalid command \�^c�v��rR
```

And once it ended, it left this string *pre-entered* on the command prompt:

```
62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c
```

If I press enter to that, I merely get a lot of `command not found` errors.

Most puzzlingly, a new file has showed up at `/home/myuser` (i.e. same level where `latest.dump` is kept). It has the bizarre name `???2@ؾ>?yqus????>I?[ޏI??i?Ď`.

If I try to `sudo rm ???2@ؾ>?yqus????>I?[ޏI??i?Ď`, I get `rm: cannot remove ‘???2@ؾ’: No such file or directory`. And then if I do `ls` again, I see two *new* files in /home/myuser other than `latest.dump` and `???2@ؾ>?yqus????>I?[ޏI??i?Ď`. These new files being `?yqus????` and `I?[ޏI??i?Ď`. I can delete these two, but never `???2@ؾ>?yqus????>I?[ޏI??i?Ď`. I notice that the two newly created files' names are part of the file name of the original file (where they appear separated by `>` if you look closely).

By the way, I logged into my postgres DB to see if the restore had worked. It hadn't, no data was populated and `psql mydb < latest.dump` essentially failed.

Can anyone point out what the hell is going on here and how can I remove these newly created errant file(s)?

---

Inside `latest.dump`, I see SQL like:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^A^A^@^@^@^@^F^@^@^@public^A^A^@^@^@^@^N^@^@^@uauvuro0s8b9v4^@^E^@^@^@false^@^C^@^@^@246^A^A^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ñ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@1259^@^E^@^@^@44416^@^R^@^@^@links_grouptraffic^@^E^@^@^@TABLE^@^B^@^@^@^@±^@^@^@CREATE TABLE links_grouptraffic (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    visitor_id integer NOT NULL,
    which_group_id integer NOT NULL,
    "time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

And a lot of data 'gibberish' like:

```
¿f ^?zQUò}ÛMpá#"        ^]äR¡g¤^E ¼å<9a>ÓÍ@î<98>,£+DØñW[^Mw<8f>Ív<9d>ñItâduM§[/úµ<8c>ÏVgý[D^W3^N^Z0<91>Õ]'/Ý¸1<8c>Ã^T°<8b>ªÈw42Á<87>Ç@o#Ñ<99>á<9c>¹=^@/áÙ¢<8c>´M Sç<90>|<æÇ<9d><93>¥<9a>NÜ©^CáxuXÜî¬<89>Ü^NÙo<8c>ð³°^O§ p¸ñÌÔ3}+^Oâr<3M¾<9b>t<80>^D<84>A^CÈ<89>kå^^H±yò ­T^Bíâ"º d<85><85><88>o<89><80>±³^C¥Ä9½^V^W4<81>æ¨ïo^YO[(æÃù^M^RÁ<9e>Ò<8e>Ô§k=ý<87>vGõº><83>^Q^DÅ>Û<~¡Ô+í
```

*Note: please ask for more information in case needed*

Comment: Your dump is not UTF-8 encoded or perhaps does not contain sql statements at all.

Comment: It's from an application that is currently in production and running correctly. I used `heroku pg:backups capture` and `curl -o latest.dump heroku pg:backups public-url` to take the dump. My application is a chat app and it's possible some users have typed non-UTF8 characters. Is there anything I need to do differently when taking the pg_dump?

Comment: have you taken a look at the dump? it sounds like possible encoding issues but you're going through many layers of indirection. what does heroku dump in? what is the default encoding of your db? 'someone typed a silly character' alone is probably not the root cause here.

Comment: @pvg: I added to the question's body a sampling of the stuff I see inside `latest.dump`. Have a look. Is that correct SQL (because I see some character strings there that I don't know the purpose of, e.g. `^@^@^@^@^@^A^A^@^@^@^@^F^@^@^@`). Overall, it seems I'll have to this to be a UTF-8 compliant data dump at the source (which happens to be Heroku btw)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to delete your file. Try using rm "filename" (i.e. put quotes around filename). If that doesn't work, the `?` in the filename is probably some other character. You can still delete it using its inode. Do `ls -li` and note the inode number (at the left hand side). Next, simply run the command `find . -inum <inode-number> -exec rm -i {} \;`. That should get rid of problem number 1.

Secondly, I suggest not using `psql mydb < latest.dump`. Instead use pg_restore like so: `pg_restore latest.dump -d mydb -U myuser`. Technically, that's the right way to go ahead for you. You may get further errors, but they won't be related to what you're seeing currently (and might even be ignorable). `latest.dump` is probably a binary file, instead of being a text file. Good luck!